# iOS, Swift, XCode: Why is the position of my elements different for different devices?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, constraints

This is how my View Controller looks like in iPhone8:

[image: iPhone8 VC in Storyboard]

This is how it looks like in iPhone8 plus:

[image: iPhone8 Plus VC in Storyboard]

As you can see, the position of the buttons in iPhone8 plus looks off compared to iPhone8.
Is there a way to fix this? I want the positions of my elements to look consistent on all iPhone versions not just iPhone8.
Thanks

Comment: have you used auto layout?

Comment: What do you use to layout the buttons?

Comment: Yes I have used Auto Layout and that didn't seem to work

Comment: You need to show how you have layers out the buttons.  Code?  Constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `UIStackView` for it
first put 1st row in stackview, then 2nd row in another stackView likewise put all the rows in separate stackView.

After all rows completed, put all the stackViews in one stackView.

and change the distribution property of each stackView to equally distributed by going to attribute inspector
.